# CSS Table with Fixed Columns

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make some columns fixed in the CSS table, provided is the HTML and CSS of the table. here table-content is scrollable in both x and y-axis, but what I'm trying to do is make fixedCells fixed and the rest of the columns in the row should be scrollable.

is it possible to do this with the below HTML structure?

```
<div class="table-content">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
         <div class="row1">
             <div class="fixedCells">
                 <div class="cell cell11">
                     text 1:1
                 </div>
                 <div class="cell cell12">
                     text 1:2
                 </div>
             </div>
              <div class="cell cell13">
                 text 1:3
              </div>
              <div class="cell cell14">
                 text 1:4
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row2">
             <div class="fixedCells">
                 <div class="cell cell21">
                     text 2:1
                 </div>
                 <div class="cell cell22">
                     text 2:2
                 </div>
             </div>
              <div class="cell cell23">
                 text 2:3
              </div>
              <div class="cell cell24">
                 text 2:4
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>

.tableContent {
   position: absolute;
   top: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #DDD;
   height: 100px;
   width : 300px;
   overflow: scroll;
}

.content-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
}

.row1 {
   position: absolute;
   height: 25px;
   width: 400px;
   top: 0px;
}

.row2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 400px;
  top: 25px;
}

.fixedCells {
   position: sticky;
   z-index: 10;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   width: 400px;
   height: 25px;
}

.cell {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 25px;
}

.cell11, cell21{
   left: 0px;
}
.cell12, cell22{
   left: 100px;
}
.cell13, cell23{
   left: 200px;
}
.cell14, cell24{
   left: 300px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure was wrong. Also the names of the HTML items and those in the CSS wasn't the same. Try this:

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x:scroll;  
}
.table-content {
   border: 1px solid #DDD;
   height: 100px;
   width : 800px;
   display:table;
   
}

.table-content .row {
    display: table-row;
}
.table-content .row div {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: white;
    padding: 5px;   
}

.table-content .row .cell11,
.table-content .row .cell21 {
    position: sticky;
    left:0; 
    z-index:2;
    border-right: 3px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="table-content">

         <div class="row row1">
               <div class="cell cell11">
                     text 1:1
               </div>
               <div class="cell cell12">
                     text 1:2
               </div>
              <div class="cell cell13">
                 text 1:3
              </div>
              <div class="cell cell14">
                 text 1:4
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row row2">

               <div class="cell cell21">
                     text 2:1
               </div>
               <div class="cell cell22">
                     text 2:2
               </div>

              <div class="cell cell23">
                 text 2:3
              </div>
              <div class="cell cell24">
                 text 2:4
              </div>
         </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not possible with absolute position styles ?